# Linking libraries in c++

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

I have a C++ file **a.cpp** with the library dependency in the path /home/name/lib and the name of the library **abc.so**.

I do the compilation as follows:

```
g++ a.cpp -L/home/name/lib -labc
```

This compiles the program with no errors. 
However while running the program, I get the ERROR:

./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libabc.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

However if before running the program, I add the library path as

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/name/lib;
```

and compile and run now, it works fine.

**Why am I not able to link the library by giving it from the g++ command?**

Comment: "...and compile and run now, it works fine. " - I don't suppose you just updated the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and reran your program *without* recompiling? That may tell you something. You *did* link to the library (more specifically, the export table to resolve your references therein). The loader still needs to know where it is to provide that functionality at *run-time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because shared object libraries are linked at runtime - you either need to add the location to the library search path (as you've done), place it somewhere within an already existing path (like `/usr/lib`), or add a symbolic link to an existing library path that links to the location where it exists.

If you want to compile the library in so there is no runtime dependency, you'll need a static library (which would be `abc.a`) - note that this has numerous downsides, however (if the library is updated, you'll need to recompile your executable to incorporate that update).

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I not able to link the library by giving it from the g++ command?

You are able to link, and you did link the library succesfully. Otherwise you would not be able to build executable (in your case a.out). The problem you mixed 2 different things: linking with shared libraries and loading them at runtime. Loading shared libraries is a pretty complex concept and described pretty well here [Program-Library-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) read from 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You are linking dynamically, is the default behavior with GCC. LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used to specify directories where to look for libraries (is a way of enforce using an specific library), read: [Program-Library-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) for more info. There is also an ld option -rpath to specify libraries search path for the binary being compiled (this info is written in the binary and only used for that binary, the LD_LIBRARY_PATH affect other apps using the same library, probably expecting a new or old version).

Linking statically is possible (but a little tricky) and no dependency would be required (but sometimes is not recommended, because prevent the update of the dependent libraries, for example for security reason, in static linking your always are using the versions of the libraries you have when compiled the binary).